# jquery mobile - are data roles inherited on the same tags?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

Here is my problem: I have an `<a>` tag with `data-role="button"`, now inside this `a` tag I would like to have another link, but the inside link should not be a button, it should be regular link. It seems like right now the inner `<a>` is inhering from the outer one and I got button inside a button. Is there any way to fix this? thanks!

Comment: what is the rational for having an anchor inside of a button anchor?

Comment: Actually I just thought of this. I need something like: when you click on the whole button besides the inside anchor, it'll take you to product page. If you click on the inside anchor, it'll add the product to cart

Comment: Would a Split List View work? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html

Comment: That doesnt sound very intuitive for the user. Also since you are using jquerymobile I am assuming this is for use on smartphones. With that in consideration it would be difficult for a user to be able to click precisely either on the link or not

Comment: It'll be a a large button, but it just needs to have different url to go to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a Split List View work?

- jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html